# Word for testing times

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word (singular or plural) to refer to a time of testing. A time when a person (or organization/civilization) is put to the test and, if they pass, they will come out of it changed for the better and stronger than ever.

Some examples:

- They were testing times for the greek, but they became even stronger
  and more resolute after their _____________.
- I have my finals next week. You could say it's gonna be my ___________.
- Next month, the company is under a goverment inspection. It's gonna be a ___________ to them.

The words provided don't need to fit perfectly in those examples; minor variations/rephrasing is allowed

Answer (score 1):

**1.Ordeal**
noun
1.
any extremely severe or trying test, experience, or trial.
2.
a primitive form of trial to determine guilt or innocence by subjecting the accused person to fire, poison, or other serious danger, the result being regarded as a divine or preternatural judgment.

**2.Acid test**
noun
1.
a severe and conclusive test to establish quality, genuineness, worth, etc.

source:dictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase you're looking for is "Judgement Day".

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/judgment%20day

Comment: No, sorry, but that's not a good fit for my case. I'm trying to avoid specific references, or implications that the event is unique. Something like _"Tribulation"_ would maybe fit better

Comment: This is not an answer because it does not say why you think it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word **'trial'** to be suited to your needs.

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define%20trial&client=safari&hl=en-in&sxsrf=AJOqlzViV9oy_WccjlO9Z4NOy_HWdNI1mw%3A1675401893160&ei=pZrcY-CwCaOSjuMPyPG1oA8&ved=0ahUKEwigl8q1zvj8AhUjiWMGHch4DfQQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=define%20trial&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6CAgAEIAEELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToFCAAQkQJKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQxwlYxCpgiyxoAnABeACAAbABiAHYD5IBBDAuMTOYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) describes it as below:

**trial**
*noun*

*a person, experience, or situation that tests a person's endurance or forbearance.*

*"this winter has been a trial for me, physically and emotionally*"

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a **crucible,** defined [by The Free Dictionary as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crucible)

> An extremely difficult experience or situation; a severe test or trial